# ¿Porque no se inserta mi valor en mi base de datos?

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

Esperando que todos se encuentren de lo mejor, se me ha presentado un inconveniente (Quizas de novato) al querer guardar información en mi base de datos desde php a MySQL.

**Describiendo el flujo de trabajo de mi pequeño sitio web.**

Anteriormente solicite la ayuda en esta pagina para lograr que en base a un clic "detonante" que actualizara un div en concreto donde estaría la información.
Ya he logrado eso, muchas gracias. Ahora, en una cierta actualización del div, llego a una donde se consiste en ver algunas entradas ya hechas y un apartado para poder hacer un comentario, un formulario mas en concreto. Ahí básicamente solo esta un textarea para insertar el comentario en si, los demás datos los recojo de la sesión en curso y demás (Ya enfatizaremos adelante), y un botón el cual, en teoría se supone que debe detonar un cierto código php para insertar el registro en cuestión.

**¿Qué he intentado?**

En base a los amplios video tutoriales que encontramos de php y mysql en todo internet, la metodología es casi la misma en si, pero por extraño que parezca, a mi no me funciona.

Lo que tengo actualmente en mi código es lo siguiente:

```
<form action="" class="ejemplo" method="POST">

    <!-- <input type="text" name="respuesta"> -->
    <input type="submit" name="guardar" value="Enviar respuesta">

    <textarea name="respuesta" name="respuesta"></textarea>

    <?php 
        //if (isset($_POST['guardar'])) {
            $textor = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['respuesta']);
            //if(empty($textor)){
                echo "<font>Introduzca algo!</font>";
            //}else{
                $fechareg = date('d-m-Y H:i:s');
                echo $fechareg;
                echo $textor;
                $sentencia = "INSERT INTO respuestas(n_control, id_pregunta, contenido, fecha) VALUES ('{$_SESSION['usuario']}','{$id}', '{$textor}', '{$fechareg}')";
                $result = mysqli_query($con, $sentencia);

            //}
        //}
    ?>

</form>
```

Antes le aclaro, usted vera el if con el isset comentado, ya que, si ignoro esa validación SI ejecuta la consulta, pero mal hecho, el usuario lo respeta, el id también, el contenido lo pone en blanco, y la fecha como 0000-00-00 00:00:00.
Lo raro también, es que en los echo de las variables donde se supone que esta la fecha, esta sale bien, se imprime correctamente, el texto sigue en blanco.

Ahora bien, cuando se ejecuta esa parte de código, se imprime:

```
Warning: Undefined array key "respuesta" in C:\xampp\htdocs\pag\ver_datos.php on line 80
```

Como si no existiera el "respuesta", pero esta bien planteado en el formulario en su name.
Si dejo el if del isset, solo actualiza la pagina y no hace absolutamente nada, nisiquiera inserta.
También usted puede admirar que lo intente con un simple input text y del mismo modo no lo reconoce, no recupera su texto.

Escuche que tambien se puede hacer por medio de ajax, pero no sabria como ocuparlo, soy novato aqui. Del mismo modo hacerlo en un php aparte, pero no encuentro como pasar las veriables como el id.

Agrego el codigo de como se obtiene el id y el usuario (Asi es, en base a lo seleccionado anteriormente, obtengo el id con post):

```
<?php 
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $titulo = $_POST['titulo'];
    include("conexion.php");
    $con=conectar();
    session_start();
?>
```

Si es de utilidad le comento que arriba recibo demas comentarios de otros usuarios. Eso funciona correctamente.

¿Por qué es que ni siquiera reconoce el name del input, y la fecha la imprime bien pero al mandarla a la base de datos la pone en 0's?
¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: Si sacaste el if isset, y se ejecuto, el problema era por ahi ;).. queria decir que no venian datos..

Comment: A mí me funciona su código, si me llega "respuesta" del textarea. Lo que no me llega son los id y titulo, y es evidente porque no están en el form

Comment: Okey, los verifico y regreso.

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos!, con la respuesta de Jorge B ha funcionado. Y lo de las fechas, estaba poniendo en un formato que no era, por ello no las aceptaba.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por que el php dentro del form ?
Eso se procesa una vez enviado el form en este caso por post.

Esto es basicamente para el envio por POST de un form a php.

index.php

```
<form action="envio.php" class="ejemplo" method="POST">
    <textarea name="respuesta" name="respuesta"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="guardar" value="Enviar respuesta">
</form>
```

envio.php

```
  <?php 
         if (isset($_POST['guardar'])) {
            $textor = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['respuesta']);
             
             if(empty($textor)){
                echo "<font>Introduzca algo!</font>";
            }else{
                $fechareg = date('d-m-Y H:i:s');
                echo $fechareg;
                echo $textor;
                $sentencia = "INSERT INTO respuestas(n_control, id_pregunta, contenido, fecha) VALUES ('{$_SESSION['usuario']}','{$id}', '{$textor}', '{$fechareg}')";
                $result = mysqli_query($con, $sentencia);

            }
        }
    ?>
```

Para enviar otro tipo de dato en el form, como el obtenido de alguna consulta, lo podes hacer a traves de un campo oculto del form:

```
<input type='hidden' name='n_control' value='<?php echo $n_control;?>'>
<input type='hidden' name='id_pregunta' value='<?php echo $id_pregunta;?>'>
```

Comment: Ha funcionado!
No sabia el tema del hidden en los inputs, muchas gracias.
Una disculpa si es muy de novatos mi pregunta, apenas inicio en esto.